# Grails upload image

Tags: grails, file-upload

I am trying to upload a picture, and save it in database.
If I do the following I get this error:

Failed to convert property value of type

> org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile to
>   required type java.lang.Byte[] for property picture1; nested exception
>   is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile] to
>   required type [java.lang.Byte] for property picture1[0]:
>   PropertyEditor
>   [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor]
>   returned inappropriate value

If i do it this way:

```
if(request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest){
    MultipartHttpServletRequest mpr = (MultipartHttpServletRequest)request;
    CommonsMultipartFile f = (CommonsMultipartFile) mpr.getFile("picture1");
}
```

I get this error:

> Executing action [save] of controller [com.testapp.RequestController]
>   caused exception: Cannot cast object '
>   org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@34ae1f02'
>   with class 
>   'org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile' to
>   class 'java.lang.Byte'

What should I do to make this work?

***Domain***

```
package com.testapp

class Request{  
    String requestID
    Date dateCreated
    String subject
    String startedBy 
    String description
    String status
    String priority 
    Productline productline
    Topic topic
    Subtopic subtopic
    String company
    Byte [] picture1
    Byte [] picture2
    Byte [] picture3
    String acceptedBy 


    static constraints = {
        requestID(blank:true,nullable:true)
        dateCreated(blank:true,nullable:true)
        subject()
        description(maxSize:5000)
        status (blank:true,nullable:true)
        priority(inList:["Normal","Urgent","Not urgent"])
        productline(blank:true,nullable:true)
        topic(blank:true,nullable:true)
        subtopic(blank:true,nullable:true)
        company(blank:true,nullable:true)
        startedBy(blank:true,nullable:true)
        acceptedBy(blank:true,nullable:true)
        picture1(blank:true,nullable:true)
        picture2(blank:true,nullable:true)
        picture3(blank:true,nullable:true)
    }

}
```

***GSP:***

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="layout" content="main" />
    <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'request.label', default: 'Request')}" />
    <title><g:message code="New request" args="[entityName]" /></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <span class="menuButton"><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message  `code="default.home.label"/></a></span>`
        <span class="menuButton"><g:link class="list" action="userList"><g:message code="Lista zahteva" `args="[entityName]" /></g:link></span>`
    </div>
<div class="body">
        <h1><g:message code="New request" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
        <g:if test="${flash.message}">
        <div class="message">${flash.message}</div>
        </g:if>
        <g:hasErrors bean="${requestInstance}">
        <div class="errors">
            <g:renderErrors bean="${requestInstance}" as="list" />
        </div>
</g:hasErrors>
        <g:form action="save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="dialog">
                <table>
                    <tbody>

                        <tr class="prop">
                            <td valign="top" class="name">
                                <label for="subject"><g:message code="request.subject.label" default="Subject" /></label>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: requestInstance, field: 'subject', 'errors')}">
                                <g:textField name="subject" value="${requestInstance?.subject}" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="prop">
                            <td valign="top" class="name">
                                <label for="description"><g:message code="request.description.label" default="Opis" /></label>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: requestInstance, field: 'description', 'errors')}">
                                <g:textArea name="description" cols="40" rows="5" value="${requestInstance?.description}" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" class="name">
                                <label for="picture1"><g:message code="request.picture1.label" default="Printscreen" /></label>
                            </td>           

                            <td valign="top" class="value">
                                <input type="file" id="picture1" name="picture1"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="prop">
                            <td valign="top" class="name">
                                <label for="priority"><g:message code="request.priority.label" default="Priority" /></label>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: requestInstance, field: 'status', 'errors')}">
                                <g:select name="priority" from="${requestInstance.constraints.priority.inList}" value="${requestInstance?.priority}" valueMessagePrefix="request.priority"  />
                            </td>
                        </tr>



                        <tr class="prop">
                            <td valign="top" class="name">
                                <label for="productline"><g:message code="request.productline.label" default="Productline" /></label>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: requestInstance, field: 'productline', 'errors')}">
                                <g:select name="productline.id" from="${com.testapp.Productline.list()}" optionKey="id" value="${requestInstance?.productline?.id}"  />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="prop">
                            <td valign="top" class="name">
                                <label for="topic"><g:message code="request.topic.label" default="Topic" /></label>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: requestInstance, field: 'topic', 'errors')}">
                                <g:select name="topic.id" from="${com.testapp.Topic.list()}" optionKey="id" value="${requestInstance?.topic?.id}"  />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="prop">
                            <td valign="top" class="name">
                                <label for="subtopic"><g:message code="request.subtopic.label" default="Subtopic" /></label>
                            </td>
                            <td valign="top" class="value ${hasErrors(bean: requestInstance, field: 'subtopic', 'errors')}">
                                <g:select name="subtopic.id" from="${com.testapp.Subtopic.list()}" optionKey="id" value="${requestInstance?.subtopic?.id}"  />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <span class="button"><g:submitButton name="create" class="save" value="${message(code: 'default.button.create.label', default: 'Create')}" /></span>
            </div>
        </g:form>
        </div>
</body>
```

***Controller:***

```
def save = {
    def requestInstance = new Request(params)
    def requestNumberInstance = new RequestNumber()
            def upPic1 = request.getFile('picture1') 

    def lastReqNum = RequestNumber.find("from RequestNumber ORDER BY requestNumber desc")
    if(lastReqNum){
        requestNumberInstance.requestNumber = lastReqNum.requestNumber + 1
    }
    else{
        requestNumberInstance.requestNumber = 110000
    }


    requestInstance.requestID = "CSC" + requestNumberInstance.requestNumber
    def currentUserContact =  Contact.findByUser(springSecurityService.getCurrentUser())
    requestInstance.startedBy = currentUserContact.realname
    requestInstance.company = currentUserContact.company
    requestInstance.status = "Opened"
    requestInstance.acceptedBy = "Not yet accepted"
            requestInstance.picture1 = upPic1


    if(requestNumberInstance.save()){



        if (requestInstance.save()) {
            flash.message = "${message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'request.label', default: 'Request'), requestInstance.id])}"
            redirect(action: "show", id: requestInstance.id)
        }
        else {
            render(view: "create", model: [requestInstance: requestInstance])
        }
    }
    else{
         render(view: "create", model: [requestInstance: requestInstance])
    }
}
```

Please dont mind the spaghetti code. I'm just trying to get some basic concepts. I will clear it later.

Simplified example:

```
def save = {
    def requestInstance = new Request(params)
    def requestNumberInstance = new RequestNumber()

    if(requestInstance.validate() && requestInstance.save(flush: true)){
        println "Saved successfully with ${requestInstance.picture1.length} bytes"
    } 
    else {
        println "Save failed"
    }
```

Comment: Providing the relevant controller and domain code would also help.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question. Follow-up: how does your controller bind the request parameters to the domain?

Comment: See my updated answer re: your latest question update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only worked when I changed my domain properties picture1,picture2,picture3 to:

```
byte [] picture1
byte [] picture2
byte [] picture3
```

and added those mappings:

```
    static mapping = {
    picture1 column:"picture1", sqlType: "blob"
    picture2 column:"picture2", sqlType: "blob"
    picture3 column:"picture3", sqlType: "blob"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Update after question edit**

The error is probably caused by this:

```
def upPic1 = request.getFile('picture1') 
...
requestInstance.picture1 = upPic1
```

`request.getFile()` is returning a MultipartFile, and you're trying to assign it to a `Byte[]` field. Considering my small example (below), you shouldn't even need to try to make this assignment. The `def requestInstance = new Request(params)` will bind the `byte[]` automatically.

---

Uploaded files bind automatically to `byte[]` fields. Here's a working example:

Domain: `grails-app/domain/my/Example.groovy`

```
package my

class Example {
    byte[] file
}
```

Controller: `grails-app/controllers/my/ExampleController.groovy`

```
package my

class ExampleController {
    def create = { }

    def save = {
        def example = new Example(params)
        if(example.validate() && example.save(flush: true)) {
            println "Saved successfully with ${example.file.length} bytes"
        } else {
            println "Save failed"
        }

        redirect(action: 'create')
    }
}
```

GSP: `grails-app/views/example/create.gsp`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <g:uploadForm action="save">
      <input type="file" name="file"/>
      <g:submitButton name="submit"/>
    </g:uploadForm>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I upload a small file using the GSP form, I see the following console output:

```
Saved successfully with 23 bytes
```

**Suggestions**

- Try using Grails data binding to save your file contents.
- Make sure your form is a `<g:uploadForm>` or has an `enctype="multipart/form-data" if you're using a vanilla``.
- Make sure you're binding the params using the domain constructor, `domain.properties`, or `bindData()`.

Comment: I've tried what you've suggested but it's still not working. I'm still getting error:      Failed to convert property value of type org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile to required type java.lang.Byte[] for property picture1; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile] to required type [java.lang.Byte] for property picture1[0]: PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value

Comment: @drago - What exactly did you try? I assume you removed the two lines I reference in my update? Just looking for some clarification there.

Comment: Yes, I removed the two lines and I also tried what Oliver Tynes suggested. Neither worked. I am starting to thing I'm overlooking something basic. But what?

Comment: I'll have to have a look at it later; you're right though, something seems awry. In the meantime, maybe whittle your code down to the smallest possible case that reproduces the issue. That might help your debugging.

Comment: I just did that and I posted it in the end of my question. Still not working.

Comment: Quick suggestion - you could try changing your domain type from `Byte[]` to `byte[]` and see if that helps. I'm not sure it will, though. Worth a try.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing your typing is messed up.

What happens if you simply do:

```
def f = request.getFile('myFile')
```

as described in the manual. If you want strong typing it should be MultiPartfile, not CommonsMultiPartFile, as far as I remember (and you get it right from the request object).

This is the interface you're working on: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html

The relevant method for you, should be getBytes().

Edit for edited question:

As I said, you want getBytes(), you are trying to shove a MultiPartFile into a byte array, thats not going to work.

`requestInstance.picture = upPic.getBytes()` and you should be allright.

Comment: This is what I did: def picture1 = request.getFile('picture1')
requestInstance.picture1 = picture1.getBytes()

Comment: I get this:
Failed to convert property value of type org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile to required type java.lang.Byte[] for property picture1; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile] to required type [java.lang.Byte] for property picture1[0]: PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor] returned inappropriate value

Comment: What is the line reference you get for that (paste the code on that line too)? That error does not look like it belongs to the code example you posted in your above comment.

Comment: I know what you mean, but thats the right code. I posted the solution that works. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't notice that you had Byte instead of byte, sorry about that.